# nuodb | Database in font end lost

Tags: sql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nuodb

I have created new Instance use ami of nuodb on amazon ec2.
My instance details:

```
AMI ID : ami-9f9201af
Root Device: ebs
Type: m1.large
location in : oregon
License: Developer Edition
```

I have found problem; when I create database, by set archive directory on /var/testdatabase,
journal directory on /var/testdatabasejournal both directory set permisson to 777 and wommit Mode in local,

After I config all database is created, but after I stop the instance and start it again my database lost from nuodb font-end.

So I checked on my archive directory and journal directory. I found file that was create after I have create database still have.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the current version of NuoDB does not restart the database automatically when the OS is restarted. There is a fix coming for this the NuoDB Automation Console but until then the following doc page should help you resolve this;
http://doc.nuodb.com/display/doc/Restart+a+NuoDB+Database